Is there a way to show only speech recognition in Jodit Editor
I am trying to put speech recognition on a textarea using Jodit Editor. My code is
<textarea name="message" id="messageadd" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>

And the initilization is like this
var messageadd = Jodit.make('#messageadd', {
        buttons: ['speechRecognition']
    });

This initiates the Jodit Editor, but instead of having only speech option it has all the options enabled by default.

